# Petapoco MVC Example

Tags: asp.net-mvc, petapoco

Where can I find an example of a MVC large solution that has been made with **Petapoco**?

Comment: Are you interested in code examples or just production application using PetaPoco? Because @DimaPasko seems to provide code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using PetaPoco with MVC. However, I'm using [Managed Extensibility Framework (Mef)](http://mef.codeplex.com/) and the [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). I only state this since your solution shouldn't care if it's PetaPoco, Entity Framework or any other Data Access Layer (DAL). Your end result should be not to tightly couple any framework to your solution - when applicable of course. You'll most likely see the repository pattern in the examples listed by @BalusC - which are great examples by the way.

So, not really on topic with your question, but I think its important to start with the right question - which should be "How should I integrate PetaPoco with a large MVC solution" Think about using PetoPoco with some sort of Dependency Injection like [NinJect](http://ninject.org/) or using Mef to "import" your repositories.

I hope this helps.